# Cucumber tags are not working after Cypress and cucumber-preprocessor upgrade

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I upgraded `Cypress` from `9.5.2` to **`10.3.0`** and previously I was using `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`:`4.3.1` now I upgrade it to **`@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`:`^11.4.0`**.

Before the upgrade, I was using `cypress-tags` for running the test using command

```
npx cypress-tags run --env TAGS="@regression" --browser chrome
```

but after the upgrade it's throwing me below error.

```
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
```

Please find the sample feature below

```
Feature: Login Features

    @regression
    Scenario: Test sample login
        Given I login to the website as "testUser"
```

Can someone help me to get an alternate option for running tests based on the tags with the latest Cypress and cucumber?

Comment: Where have you mentioned the tag `regression`? Is it in your step definition files?

Comment: no, it's in my feature files.

Comment: Can you add your feature file showing the tags to the question.

Comment: Yes, I just added it in the description now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TLDR**

Just remove `cypress-tags` altogether, but a good enhancement is to add `filterSpecs` and `omitFiltered` options.

---

From this page [Transfer of ownership](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/689)

> The `cypress-tags` has been removed and made redundant. Specs containing no matching scenarios are automatically filtered, provided that `filterSpecs` is set to true.

So, if I run

```js
npx cypress run --env tags="@regression"
```

I get results like

```js
      Spec                                              Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped  
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ √  duckduckgo.feature                         0ms        -        -        -        -        - │
  ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
  │ √  duckduckgo2.feature                      00:04        1        1        -        -        - │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    √  All specs passed!                        00:04        1        1        -        -        -
```

which has done the job (duckduckgo2.feature has the regression tag).

But it's better with these two config options

**package.json**

```js
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.3.1",
    "cypress": "^10.3.0",
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "filterSpecs": true,
    "omitFiltered": true
  }
}
```

I now get

```js
     Spec                                              Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped  
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ √  duckduckgo2.feature                      00:04        1        1        -        -        - │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    √  All specs passed!                        00:04        1        1        -        -        -
```

---

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const createBundler = require("@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
const createEsbuildPlugin = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild");

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  on(
    "file:preprocessor",
    createBundler({
      plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin.default(config)],
    })
  );

  return config;
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    supportFile: false,
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
});
```

Comment: I added these options in **package.json**, but now it's running all the features even though I added the regression tag in one feature. :(

Comment: It worked for me, perhaps `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.4.0` is different. I'll take a look.

Comment: Can you share your **cypress.config.js** file? I don't think it's the issue with the version. I downgraded my version to 11.3.1 but still it's running all the features.

Comment: Installed very latest `"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.5.1"` and the tag worked ok.

Comment: `"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "11.4.0"` is ok for me too.

Comment: But how to have multiple tags ?

Comment: Use commas, as shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative that has been updated for Cypress 10 is [cypress-grep](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-grep).

One of it's features is the run tests by tag,

**Start grepping by title and tags:**

```js
# run only the tests with "auth user" in the title
$ npx cypress run --env grep="auth user"

# run tests with "hello" or "auth user" in their titles
# by separating them with ";" character
$ npx cypress run --env grep="hello; auth user"

# run tests tagged @fast
$ npx cypress run --env grepTags=@fast

# run only the tests tagged "smoke"
# that have "login" in their titles
$ npx cypress run --env grep=login,grepTags=smoke

# only run the specs that have any tests with "user" in their titles
$ npx cypress run --env grep=user,grepFilterSpecs=true

# only run the specs that have any tests tagged "@smoke"
$ npx cypress run --env grepTags=@smoke,grepFilterSpecs=true

# run only tests that do not have any tags
# and are not inside suites that have any tags
$ npx cypress run --env grepUntagged=true
```

Comment: Will cypress-grep work with cucumber?

Comment: I've not tried the two in combination, but I would expect so since `cypress-tags` was not specific to cucumber but did work with it.

Comment: I just tried this, but (as for now) it doesn't seem to work with cucumber

Comment: Yes it works with @badeball/cypress-cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

From terminal try below command,
npx cypress run --spec '**/*.feature' -e TAGS='@NonCrud' --browser chrome --headless

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
you can create config file like this 
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
const browserify = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/browserify");

 

 

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  
await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
on("file:preprocessor", browserify.default(config));
return config;
}

 

 

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents,
    baseUrl:'',
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/bdd-cucumber/features/*.feature",
    watchForFileChanges:false,
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode: true,
    defaultCommandTimeout: 10000
},
});


and trigger cypress using npx cypress --config-file file --browser browser --env tags='tagname'
```

Answer (score 0):

please be aware that when you use tags with: and, or, inverted or not tags it uses a different syntax for [@cypress/grep](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/npm/grep#or-tags) and [cucumber tags](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=javascript) (please look on the "Tag expressions" section).

According to the @suchanignorantthingtodo-ukr,
First, enter the tags to **cucumber tag** and then to the @cypress/grep tag.
Because, I want for example to use an "or" expression statement, and because those tags are eventually a single string, I just use the replace function to fit between the two approaches/plugins.

For example:
For cucumber tags, I use the expression statement:
'@night or @instalttion'
And for @cypress/grep tags, I use the expression statement:
'@night @instalttion'.
So I just use the function:

```
on("file:preprocessor", webpackPreprocessor(webpackOptions));
cucumberConfig.env.grepTags = cucumberConfig.env.tags.replace('or', ' ')
const grepConfig = require('@cypress/grep/src/plugin')(cucumberConfig);
```

PS,
I also recommend you use:

```
grepOmitFiltered: true
```

To avoiding to see that tests are skipped because of tags.
But this is only my preference :)