# Why is Cypress version 12 not recognizing my Cucumber tags?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, ui-automation

I am trying to use tags in cypress cucumber for cypress version 12 , however when trying to run the tags, its running the entire suite , can some on please guide me on this -:
Following are my feature file  -:

```
` @error
    Scenario: Login using valid credentials
        Given I access the university Login Portal page
        When I enter a username webdriver
        And I enter a password webdriver555
        And I click on the login button
        Then I should be presented with the following message validation failed
`
```

Cypress.config -:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;

function getConfigurationByFile(file) {
  const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve('cypress//config', `${file}.json`);

  if(!fs.existsSync(pathToConfigFile)){
    console.log("No custom config file found.")
    return {};
  }

  return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile)
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  projectId: 'e151a8',
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())

      // implement node event listeners here
      const file = config.env.configFile || ''

      return getConfigurationByFile(file)

    },
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,feature}",
    //excludeSpecPattern: "cypress/e2e/other/*.js",
    supportFile: false,
    
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    baseUrl: "http://www.webdriveruniversity.com",
    experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode: true,
    defaultCommandTimeout: 10000,
    pageLoadTimeout: 120000,
    screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
    trashAssetsBeforeRuns: true,
    videoCompression: 1,
    viewportHeight: 960,
    videoUploadOnPasses: true,
    viewportWidth: 1536,
    reporter: 'cypress-multi-reporters',
    reporterOptions: {
    configFile: 'reporter-config.json',
    },
    retries:{
      runMode: 0,
      openMode: 1
    },
    env: {
      first_name: "Sarah",
      web123: "website-url"
    },
    "experimentalStudio": true

  },
});
```

Package.json file -:

```
{
  "name": "new-cypress",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Cypres automation frmwrk",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "triggerAllTests-headless": "npx cypress run",
    "junit-merge": "npx junit-merge -d cypress/results/junit -o cypress/results/junit/results.xml",
    "delete-junit-report": "rm -rf cypress/results/junit/results.xml",
    "delete-results": "rm -rf cypress/results/* || true",
    "mochawesome-merge": "npx mochawesome-merge cypress/results/mochawesome/*.json > mochawesome.json && npx marge mochawesome.json",
    "delete-mochawesome-report": "rm -rf mochawesome-report/* || true",
    "cypress-regression-pack": "npm run delete-results && npm run delete-mochawesome-report && npm run triggerAllTests-headless && npm run mochawesome-merge",
    "triggerAllTests-staging": "npx cypress run --env configFile=staging",
    "triggerAllTests-autostore-dashboard": "npx cypress run --spec cypress/e2e/WebDriveruni-pom/* --record --key c303c454-20f9-4774-a2ec-3a0d6d283385",
    "triggerTestinWebdriveuni-pom": "npx cypress run --spec cypress/e2e/WebDriveruni-pom/test.js",
    "cypress-multi-browser": "npm run triggerTestinWebdriveuni-pom -- --browser chrome --headed & npm run triggerTestinWebdriveuni-pom -- --browser firefox --headed"
  },
  "author": "Test",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/xpath": "^2.0.3",
    
    "cypress": "^12.6.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^4.0.7",
    "cypress-xpath": "^1.4.0", 
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.6.3",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^2.2.0",
    "mochawesome": "^7.1.3",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.3.0",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^6.2.0"
  },

  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/support/step_definitions"
    
    
  }
}
```

let me know if you need any further detils.

I tried running "error" tags by using below commands-: npx cypress run --env tags="@error"

Also tried with solution. provided in the answer -:
[Cucumber tags are not working after Cypress and cucumber-preprocessor upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73076496/cucumber-tags-are-not-working-after-cypress-and-cucumber-preprocessor-upgrade)

but got error